# .htcaccess mod rewrite basics

Tags: html, mod-rewrite

I'm very bad at rewriting with .htcaccess as I rarely work with it.

I have `/sv/services.html`  it's located here in my ftp: `/public_html/mysite/sv/services.html`

How do I rewrite services.html --> services or our-services ?

I want the reult to be: mysite.com/sv/service

I would need more than

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^service$ service.html
```

An full, working example would be very nice so that I can get a better understanding in .htaccess rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

> RewriteRule ^service$ services.html [L,NC]

try to access like

> url.com/service/

Comment: are you sure about your system has privileges to url-rewriting?